# How to downsize images according to the viewport height?

Tags: html, css

The goal is to see the complete image depending on the height of the viewport. Unfortunately whenever the height of the window is downsized it overflows cropping our images. I'm using grid display so the content never overlaps or get inlined.

How can I prevent this behaviour and make it so the pictures always take 100% of the remaining spaces while keeping the aspect ratio of the images?

**The images cannot have a fixed height.**

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8jztc2sf

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.slide {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.slide > div:first-child {
  padding: 1rem 0rem 2rem;
}

.slide > div:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.slide > div:last-child img {
  max-height: 350px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-2 {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">    
    <div>
        <h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum gravida tincidunt.<br/>Integer sed consequat erat, non facilisis est. Etiam vel quam id ligula tempor feugiat vel in urna.</p>

        <a href="#">Etiam vel</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide-2">    
    <div>
        <h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum gravida tincidunt.<br/>Integer sed consequat erat, non facilisis est. Etiam vel quam id ligula tempor feugiat vel in urna.</p>

        <a href="#">Etiam vel</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set height for img and it will auto calculate width accordingly

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava The images cannot have a fixed height.

Comment: Do you need 100% of remaining height always?

Comment: Yes, the images should take what's left on small screens, for instance the height of the image should be smaller as the viewport is tiny, while on big screens the height of the image should be at it's maximum (`max-height: 350px;` in this case).

Comment: So the image needs to be downsized based on aspect ratio or stay the same height when we downsize window ; I see your problem now

Comment: I think you will need to listen to window resize event and change it when window resize

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Could be done with javascript indeed, but I'm looking for a CSS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.slide {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:auto minmax(0,1fr); /* added */
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.slide > div:first-child {
  padding: 1rem 0rem 2rem;
}

.slide > div:last-child {
  height: 100%; /* added */
  display:flex; /* added */
}

.slide > div:last-child img {
  max-height: 350px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: auto; /* moved here */
  object-fit: contain; /* added */
  object-position: bottom; /* added */
  max-width: 100%; /* added */
}

.slide-2 {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">    
    <div>
        <h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum gravida tincidunt.<br/>Integer sed consequat erat, non facilisis est. Etiam vel quam id ligula tempor feugiat vel in urna.</p>

        <a href="#">Etiam vel</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide-2">    
    <div>
        <h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis fermentum gravida tincidunt.<br/>Integer sed consequat erat, non facilisis est. Etiam vel quam id ligula tempor feugiat vel in urna.</p>

        <a href="#">Etiam vel</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that this solution doesn't keep the aspect ratio of the image on smaller screens as they get stretched, is there any possible fix for it?

Comment: @HiroyukiNuri add `object-fit: contain;
    object-position: bottom;` to the image

Comment: first of all check object-fit support, and then think about image resolution and proportionality, because images can be cropped

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove `height: 100vh;` form `.slide`, I see problems with it, instead of that add `min-height: 100%` to `body` and `height: 100%` to `html` tag if you want fluid content according to viewport height.
Then add this corrections to your images styles:

```
 .slide > div:last-child img {
    max-height: 53vh; /* or other value */
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Hope this is what you've search,  if I understood correctly what's the problem.